# Is a mutex lock used inside a shared function or outside of it

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Assume `sharedFnc` is a function that is used between multiple threads:

```
void sharedFnc(){
   // do some thread safe work here
}
```

Which one is the proper way of using a Mutex here?

A)

```
void sharedFnc(){
  // do some thread safe work here
}
int main(){
 ...
 pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
 sharedFnc();
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
 ...
}
```

Or B)

```
void sharedFnc(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  // do some thread safe work here
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
int main(){
 ...
 sharedFnc();
 ...
}
```

Comment: Both will work. The question is: does it make sense to call this function without locking the mutex?

Comment: Usually it's inside the function. That way the caller doesn't have to worry about locking.

Comment: The concept of a "shared function" is usually wrong. It's *data* that's potentially shared and needs to be synchronized between threads accessing it, not *functions*.

Comment: Both are okay. If `sharedFnc` were the only function, I might put the mutex locks inside it. But, if there were more than one function [that needed to be protected] (e.g. `sharedFnc2` and `sharedFnc3` as well), I'd do: `LOCK; sharedFnc(); sharedFnc2(); sharedFnc3(); UNLOCK`. But, I might wrap that sequence in [yet] another function [which is option B]

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider two extremes:

In the first extreme, you can't even tell what lock you need to acquire until you're inside the function. Maybe the function locates an object and operates on it and the lock is per-object. So how can the caller know what lock to hold?

And maybe the code needs to do some work while holding the lock and some work while not holding the lock. Maybe it needs to release the lock while waiting for something.

In this extreme, the lock must be acquired and released inside the function.

In the opposite extreme, the function might not even have any idea it's used by multiple threads. It may have no idea what lock its data is associated with. Maybe it's called on different data at different times and that data is protected by different locks.

Maybe its caller needs to call several different functions while holding the same lock. Maybe this function reports some information on which the thread will decide to call some other function and it's critical that state not be changed by another thread between those two functions.

In this extreme, the caller must acquire and release the lock.

Between these two extremes, it's a judgment call based on which extreme the situation is closer to. Also, those aren't the only two options available. There are "in-between" options as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's something to be said for this pattern:

```
// Only call this with `lock` locked.
//
static sometype foofunc_locked(...) {
    ...
}


sometype foofunc(...) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    sometype rVal = foofunc_locked(...);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return rVal;
}
```

This separates the *responsibility* for locking and unlocking the mutex from whatever other responsibilities are embodied by `foofunc_locked(...)`.

One reason you would want to do that is, it's very easy to see whether every possible invocation of `foofunc()` unlocks the `lock` before it returns. That might not be the case if the locking and unlocking was mingled with loops, and `switch` statements and nested `if` statements and `returns` from the middle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the lock is inside the function, you better make *damn* sure there's no recursion involved, especially no indirect recursion.

Another problem with the lock being inside the function is loops, where you have two big problems:

1. Performance. Every cycle you're releasing and reacquiring your locks. That can be expensive, especially in OS's like Linux which don't have light locks like critical sections.
2. Lock semantics. If there's work to be done inside the loop, but outside your function, you can't acquire the lock once per cycle, because it will dead-lock your function. So you have to piece-meal your loop cycle even more, calling your function (acquire-release), then manually acquire the lock, do the extra work, and manually release it before the cycle ends. And you have absolutely no guarantee of what happens between your function releasing it and you acquiring it.

Comment: Re, "...make damned sure..." You can do that by creating a "reentrant lock" object. (asuming the posix threads library doesn't already provide one.) Just another tool in the kit.